# How to get tensorflow BERT transformer to predict?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, bert-language-model

Might be a novice question, but I'm using a fine-tuned base cased BERT model trained on the yelp dataset and cannot get predict() to work. My code is below.

Code:

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import DefaultDataCollator
import tensorflow as tf

# going to train and test on yelp review dataset
dataset = load_dataset("yelp_review_full")
print(dataset["train"][10])

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")

def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["text"], padding="max_length", truncation=True)

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
# print(tokenized_datasets["train"][100])

small_train_dataset = tokenized_datasets["train"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))
small_eval_dataset = tokenized_datasets["test"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))

data_collator = DefaultDataCollator(return_tensors="tf")

tf_train_dataset = small_train_dataset.to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "token_type_ids"],
    label_cols=["labels"],
    shuffle=True,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=8,
)

tf_validation_dataset = small_eval_dataset.to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "token_type_ids"],
    label_cols=["labels"],
    shuffle=True,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=8,
)

small_train_dataset = tokenized_datasets["train"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))
small_eval_dataset = tokenized_datasets["test"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))

data_collator = DefaultDataCollator(return_tensors="tf")

tf_train_dataset = small_train_dataset.to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "token_type_ids"],
    label_cols=["labels"],
    shuffle=True,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=8,
)

tf_validation_dataset = small_eval_dataset.to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "token_type_ids"],
    label_cols=["labels"],
    shuffle=True,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=8,
)
```

I have it trained now, but am trying to use model.predict() with a string or list of strings as input with no success. How would I do this? Appreciate any insight!

Comment: What do you mean by "no success"? Is it failing to predict? Is it not predicting what you'd expect? Does the code run at all? Any error messages?

Comment: Which model do you use? I can't find your model in the code. You can use one model like this: ```model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(<fine-tuned-bert-model-for-yelp>)```